# "docker attach" vs "docker start -ai" for a running container

Tags: docker

The Docker documentation indicates the `docker attach` command is used to attach to a **running** container (at [docker container attach](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/)) and the `docker start` command is used to start **stopped** containers (at [docker container start](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/)).

However, I tried applying `docker start -ai` to a **running** container, and it looks that it can successfully attach to the running container.

So my question is *"Are `docker start -ai` and `docker attach` the same when they are used to attach to a running container?"*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the code of [docker start](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/cli/cli/command/container/start.go#L61):

```
Ln99:  resp, errAttach := dockerCli.Client().ContainerAttach(ctx, c.ID, options)
Ln136: dockerCli.Client().ContainerStart(ctx, c.ID, startOptions)
```

`docker start` consists separate `attach` & `start` operation, if the container already start, just skip this `start` operation, but `attach` still works there.

So, they are same in this scenario. BTW, from October 2014, docker team suggest to use [docker exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) to enter the container.